# buddy.hashers always generates a different hash

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm using [buddy.hashers](https://funcool.github.io/buddy-hashers/latest/) to generate and save the "hashed_password" field for my users' SQL table, but it generates different strings:

```
user=> (require '[buddy.hashers :as hashers])
 nil
 user=> (hashers/derive "password")"bcrypt+sha512$b55166651bb4e7241f1c42342bdc1ea6$12$8328fb1e4326dc920c6aff38076156da59594b264818c922"
 user=> (hashers/derive "password" "bcrypt+sha512$cf25e31d3a64f4189a9141b8f5e11aed$12$4b07f8380378f3a885f2212cfbe0d4f0901e8971d416e41e"
 user=> (hashers/derive "password")"bcrypt+sha512$3b569dc15a8d8e74b81a2e0652bf5172$12$b2bbf343ff7d94bccbadff07b2b9629eab3dde43c039106d"
 user=> (hashers/derive "password")"bcrypt+sha512$8d4081381c95220d6b9b67eef041dd89$12$8337f9b53f6b0f32cf30c01708e2135f94c284f5e768cc66"
```

why?

**UPDATE**:

```
(hashers/derive "password" {:salt "1f1v45642bzz1ea6" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using a different "salt" value each time, unless you explicitly specify a salt value. Relevant code [here](https://github.com/funcool/buddy-hashers/blob/master/src/clojure/buddy/hashers.clj#L135-L144).

If you don't specify a salt, it uses `(nonce/random-bytes 16)`. It's probably best that you *don't* specify a custom salt value. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for more.

Comment: Importantly, according to that link it doesn't just give back the hashed password: it also gives you back the salt it chose, and other metadata you should store in the database in order to be able to check the hash later.